# HTTP POST 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, post, zapier

I'm currently using Zapier to send some POST data from a TypeForm to a WordPress website to create a new user.

The POST works, I get all the variables in my script I need and a user is created.

For some reason though the POST on the zapier account or Hurl.it returns a 404 not found error. Both the domain and script are accessible and currently the only issue is that the client receives an email saying that his Zap may have an issue (because it's returning a 404). The zap test on the URL actually returns a success though.

It just seems strange that everything works but both zapier and hurl.it are returning a 404 not found error?

The request from hurl.it is:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 117
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
```

The response from hurl.it is:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 10:57:04 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
```

Anyone any ideas how I can resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: You mean `$_POST`?

Comment: Ye sorry. That's what is being used in the PHP script for the variables.

It's a HTTP POST Method though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this a few weeks ago but thought i'd just put it here in case anyone else comes across this.

The issue seemed to be with me requiring wp-blog-header.php in the file which was watching for the $_POST data. Now i'm pretty sure this was working fine at the start but i resolved this by changing the require to just be wp-load.php instead (i only needed access to a few functions).

Like i said above everything was still working with wp-blog-header.php being included it just 404ed on the zapier side and emailed the client. Something must of gone a miss in the wp() function or the template-loader.php file to cause it.